# gprof with Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, profiling, gprof

I need help with profiling my C++ Qt application on target, both memory usage and cpu load. I was recomended gprof, but can't seem to get it to work.
These are the guides I tried to follow:

- https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/index.html#Top
- http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Profiling_with_GNU_gprof

I added these flags to my .pro file

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-pg
QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-pg
```

But when I execute the program the gmon.out file is nowhere to be found?!

Can anyone give me a step-by-step example of what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Here's [*another link to follow*](http://archive.today/9r927).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG *= -pg
QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG *= -pg
```

instead of:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pg
QMAKE_LDFLAGS += -pg
```

and don't forget this:

```
CONFIG += debug
```

I had the same problem and it worked for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-pg
QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-pg
```

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Profiling_with_GNU_gprof

Answer (score 0):

I am profiling code running on an iMX-7 embedded device with GNU c++ compiler for ARM CPU. I have used that suggestion and it worked:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -pg
QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -pg
```

However, **gprof** output analysis showed 11 cycles (recursive calls) which didn't exist.

Adding more debug information at compile time (-Og) reduced cycle count from 11 to 7. Still not perfect but the remaining ones were benign:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -pg
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Og
QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -pg
```